# What are the advantages of "modern" differential geometry to solve ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I am currently learning "modern" differential geometry (i.e. in terms of vector fields, differential forms, etc, in a coordinate-free way).

I know that the study of ODEs can be rewritten in those terms, see for instance this [math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577421/the-connection-between-differential-forms-and-ode).

However, I don't really understand yet what is gained in using this language compared to what one learns in the first few years of undergrad.

I am looking for a good reference that would describe in detail how this modern view of differential geometry can be used to solve flows induced by vector fields (in particular, the existence of fixed points, perturbations of those, etc), and/or one that explains the advantages of that approach.

Skimming through Lee's introduction to differential geometry (p. 333), it seems that I am looking for a reference for "smooth dynamical systems" in this language, but I can't find something relevant online.

Comment: Speaking as a geometer (not an expert in dynamical systems): It may be helpful to read _Differential Topology_ by Guillemin and Pollack. One benefit of a global perspective is the Hopf index theorem for compact smooth manifolds, which equates the "total index" of a generic smooth vector field with the Euler characteristic of the manifold. (Another important detail is the global existence/uniqueness theory, but I'm guessing that's of less interest to you as a scientist.)

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the references. All three are really focused on dynamical systems and not really in the language of modern differential geometry, though the beginning of the first reference seems promising. 
In a sense, I'm looking for a book that revisit in that language the basics of ODEs...